# Configuring Carousel to scale down to certain size and center in dedicated area - Also scaling high res images down

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to configure carousel from Bootstrap to center my images on a webpage, scale them down from there original size to the one I set and also move the navigation buttons further in from the edges of the webpage, but I can't figure out why what I'm doing isn't working.

I've made a class around the entire carousel in attempt to make it smaller/align it to the center but it doesn't work.

Here's what it currently looks like:
http://i.imgur.com/qh7cdWx.png

Here's what I've been trying to do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ycGP.png

I'd grealy appreciate any help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to figure out how you defined your carousel classes and ids without actually seeing your codes but if you are using the default bootstrap carousel, then this should center your carousel images:

```
.carousel-inner img    {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: If you want help with resizing the images too then please post your html and css on a jsfiddle and I will help you out with that too.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks, It appears I'm incompetant though as I can't figure out how to display my code in Jsfiddle. All of what I've got is live at kurrel.com/portfolio though if that's a viable method of seeing my code.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Do mark this as the correct answer and upvote it if it helped you with your issue Kurrel :)

Comment: Checking the site now

Comment: Ok so if you want the images to maintain a fix dimension just scale all of them to a common carousel size by giving a definite height to your item class e.g.. `.item { height:300px; }` and give a height of auto for your images e.g. `.carousel-inner img { height:auto;}` and all of them will maintain a height of 300px.